# Problem with Dr. Java IDE

Tags: java, ide

I have download Dr.Java ( the latest version) and tried to open it. But it shows an error, saying that I need a Java Runtime Environment 1.5.0.

So I go to my command prompt, and I put in : "java -version". Here is the result:java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

So I clearly have Java downloaded. Is my version "too modern" for Dr.Java?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue as I was using jdk10. It seems like drJava is not compatible with new jdk10. I resolved my issue by installing jdk version 8. https://java.com/en/download/